# CSS: Using two adjacent selectors to select element after adjacent element

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I do something like this?

```
element + adjacent_element + element_to_style {
    /* somestyle */
}
```

I want to style an element that's adjacent to the adjacent element.

***EDIT:***

***This code works properly, I just forgot the `.` before the classnames. That's why it didn't work.***

Comment: That is a valid selector, which styles `element_to_style` only if it's in this structure `<element /><adjacent_element /><element_to_style />`. Or which element do you want to style?

Comment: Ah it did already work, I forgot the dot before the classnames...

Comment: `.it + .happens + .dont-worry`.

Answer (score 3):

There is `~` [general sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators). But is css3 so the browser support is limited.